# Could not load package because of error 0xC001404A

Tags: ssis

**Could not load package because of error 0xC001404A** (the execute permissions was denied on the object...) when trying to run SSIS package via command prompt on SQL Server 2008R2.

Anybody could help me, please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you perform the action as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I tried to run it with Admin rights and I got the same error!! I wonder if it is not linked to the role "db_ssisadmin". thank you for this answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during loading of SSIS package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246937/error-during-loading-of-ssis-package)

Comment: The solution I found is to add to user that execute packages these rights : db_ssisadmin, db_ssisltduser and db_ssisoperator in MSDB database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to add to user that execute packages these rights : db_ssisadmin, db_ssisltduser and db_ssisoperator in MSDB database.

```
USE msdb;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ssisadmin', N'Domain\user';
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ssisltduser', N'Domain\user';
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ssisoperator', N'Domain\user';
GO
```